# How to know the recommended version elastic search of the logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am an newbie to logstash, when I studied
[logstash sample](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html). I noticed that it said

> Each release of Logstash has a **recommended** version of Elasticsearch you 
>   should use.

But I failed to find it. I didn't see the release notes of logstash. For example, the logstash I used is 1.5.0, how to know which version elastic search I should use. In the sample above, it said I could use 1.5.1 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Logstash version including and after 1.4.2 can use any ElasticSearch version above 1.x

It is suggested to use ElasticSearch above 1.1.1 as there was a small vulnerability which has since been patched in later versions.

Using 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 will be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cand find some notes regarding the recommended ElasticSearch version in Logstash web documentation > Output plugins > ElasticSearch. Here is the link for the **current logstash version**:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html

For instance, if you want to know about the recommended Elasticsearch version for **Logstash 1.4.2**, you can visit the old documentation, here:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch

Try changing the version from the URL to get specific details for this version. For instance, for Logstash 1.3.2 you can use:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/outputs/elasticsearch

In each of these documentation references you'll find a section "VERSION NOTE" regarding the recommended ElasticSearch version.